# How can I check how much of sRGB and AdobeRGB my monitor covers in percentage?

Tags: color-management, display, srgb

I've read countless reviews such as [this one](https://www.anandtech.com/show/3754/a-new-30-contender-hp-zr30w-review/4) where reviewers, after carefully calibrating the tested monitor, are able to calculate how much of either sRGB or AdobeRGB the display is capable of cover, shown in a percentage value.

I know there are several ways to graphically see the difference (if there's any!) between a certain color space and the monitor's, but it seems I can't find anywhere a software which will tell me in percentage of much of sRGB/AdobeRGB/etc. my display is able to cover.

Does anyone know of a software which, given my monitor's calibrated ICC profile and a colorspace, will tell me in percentage how much my monitor covers?

Comment: I find the whole notion that one can describe how much of a display gamut is within sRGB or Adobe RGB as a percentage misleading. For one thing I've never seen a description of what the "percentage" is relative to. I presume it's the percentage of volume in CIE xyY space. But what about uvY space or CIELAB space which are better spaces for comparing color perception. These are all going to produce different percentages.

Answer (score 12):

The tool `displaycal-profile-info`, part of the [DisplayCAL](https://displaycal.net/) package, can do this. This works (and works basically the same way) for Windows, Mac, and Linux.

See for example for my (calibrated) ThinkPad screen:

[image: wow]

... which has a 60% coverage of sRGB and 43% coverage of Adobe RGB.

Comment: Strangely I don't get those parameters... do I have to make a new calibration using DisplayCAL to make them appear?

Comment: @Luca Hmmm — it may actually be info written into this specific profile. I'll investigate a bit.

Comment: sorry to annoy you, but another thought crossed my mind: if those are parameters which have been set in the ICC profile by the calibrator, can you tell me which software you used to produce that ICC profile?

Comment: Wait. 59.6% sRGB coverage? **Seriously?** That is actually worse than my $230 netbook, which measured at 61.2% (using a ColorMunki Display colorimeter). My netbook also happens to be made by Lenovo, and I kinda suspect this is not a coincidence...

Comment: @xiota DisplayCAL has performed external measurements to come up with the profile displayed under Profile Information.

Comment: Isn't there a Settings tool in Windows 10/11 that will just tell you if your monitor is 100% Adobe RGB? Not these third-party apps

Comment: @user610620 Maybe? I don't know anything about Windows.

Comment: @user610620 But also: that's just going to give you what the monitor manufacturer says, unlike measuring with a hardware calibration tool as I did here.

Comment: Instead of downloading an unknown hardware calibration tool, don't software image editors like GIMP auto-detect a laptop's color gamut range?

Comment: You cannot download hardware.

Comment: So does DisplayCal (I assume to be software) require a complementary hardware tool? If so, what? (Please edit into answer.)

Comment: DisplayCal is software that works with hardware calibration devices. You do not need to have such a device to display profile properties, which is what my answer is about — the question presumes already having one, so that's what I answered. If you have a different question please ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a spyder 5 pro it will give you a chart and percentages of coverage for srgb, ntsc, and adobe rbg

Here is my srgb result[image]

Comment: Most of the screen calibration tools, so called colorimeters, will show you this. so this cannot  only done with the spyder (there is also a new one now) but also with for example X-Rite’s ColorMunki series which are a little bit cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using **BasICColor Display** for *software* and an **Xrite i1 DisplayPro** for *hardware*.

After calibration and profiling the BasICColor Display will tell you your Delta E errors and your monitor's gamut size.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a Mac you can use the Colorsync App that is included within the Utilites folder for it.

Comment: I can't seem to find  a way to use it :( 
I only get the visual gamut, but cannot find any place where it says "your monitor profile covers xx% of sRGB or AdobeRGB" or whatever.
Can you kindly post a step by step guide using Colorsync?